# IELTS Academic and Canada Express Entry

Tags: canada, language, ielts, language-test

I have IELTS ""Academic"" with 7 total score and all sub-score above 6 
Can I use it for Canada Express Entry ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to take the [General Training version](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/immigrate/skilled/language-testing.asp), not the Academic version. The statement is:

> IELTS has two options for the reading and writing tests: “General
>   Training” and “Academic.” You must take the “General Training” option.